# Unknown user directory on Windows with funky file names

Tags: malware

Poking around my machine today, realised there's an unknown user listed in there: `tVA2uiJ14w`

[image]

First I thought it could be some IT account, but then again the filenames are too funky to be business related.

All of these files seems to be encoded/encrypted in some way:

Extract of the `diskapricotdeputy.sql`

```
/*******************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...
```

I would appreciate if anyone has some pointer on this, cheers.

Comment: Each file name is 3 random dictionary words with different separators. Each a different file type. And they are all created in the same minute. You got malware. Disconnect it from the network.

Comment: Turns out, these files are part of the A/V detection tools. These are canary files owned by the A/V. If these get encrypted by a malware, the A/V will then detect that a ransomeware attact is underway.